# Forcibly terminate a python script

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, while-loop

I'm writing an app with a server and client, I want to stop the server when I close the tkinter UI, but the while loop waits for the server.accept() and never terminates, even using sys.exit, it's running threaded btw. I am running a function on gui close, but it doesn't want to terminate.

Here is the example:

```
while waiting_for_connection: # This is in a threaded function
    conn, addr = server.accept() # It's stuck on this line while waiting for connection
    thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr)) # Here it connects, but it doesn't reach the end of a loop if no one connects
    thread.start()
```

Any fix for that?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Prune I edited my post, have a look!

Comment: Yes.  Now, perhaps a client-server guru will be able to help.

Comment: Did you set `daemon=True` when creating the thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely the server is waiting for non-daemon threads to exit, but they aren't because they are still waiting on active sockets. You can set `thread.daemon=True` to exit the program exit immediately and let the system close the sockets, or you can keep a list of sockets and reset/close them via an exit handler registered via `atexit.register`.

You can get fancier on exit by letting the socket communications go through some sort of a graceful termination, but that depends on the protocol you are using. As an example, suppose you want server shutdown to wait until all current data is sent. A single SIGTERM could mean to gracefully finish the current tasks at hand then exit. A SIGABRT or perhaps two SIGINTs in a row could mean to reset and get out now.